# cannot move out of borrowed content when iterating the loop

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

I'm trying to get field from my structure in rust

```
fn check_args(command: i32, args: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Argument> {
    let arg_tbl: [ArgsTable; 5] = [
        ArgsTable { cc: 0, ac: 1, dv: "4".to_string() },
        ArgsTable { cc: 1, ac: 1, dv: "4".to_string() },
        ArgsTable { cc: 1, ac: 2, dv: "in.txt".to_string() },
        ArgsTable { cc: 4, ac: 3, dv: "1".to_string() },
        ArgsTable { cc: 6, ac: 2, dv: "out.txt".to_string() },
    ];
    let mut arguments: Vec<Argument> = Vec::new();
    if args.len() == 0 {
        for arg in arg_tbl.iter() {
            if arg.cc == command {
                arguments.push(Argument {
                    code: arg.ac,
                    value: arg.dv,
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but get this error

```
    |
151 |                     value: arg.dv
    |                            ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I get the `arg.dv` field?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you copy/paste something wrong? In particular the `i` in this line seems wrong: `for i in arg_tbl.iter()`.

Comment: Damn! I'm stupid)) thanx @wimh . should change it by `arg` . But also I  cloned `arg.dv` like this: `arg.dv.clone()` and now it works

Comment: Have you had a look at all the other [cannot move out of borrowed content](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+move+out+of+borrowed+content) questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you already have an answer, I will explain the problem and provide a different solution too. I also recommend reading [Effectively Using Iterators In Rust](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html).

I'll start with a [MCVE](/help/mcve), which you can test on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) too:

```
struct ArgsTable {
    dv: String,
}

fn check_args() -> Vec<ArgsTable> {
    let arg_tbl: [ArgsTable; 2] = [
        ArgsTable {
            dv: "4".to_string(),
        },
        ArgsTable {
            dv: "out.txt".to_string(),
        },
    ];
    let mut arguments: Vec<ArgsTable> = Vec::new();
    for arg in arg_tbl.iter() {
        arguments.push(ArgsTable { dv: arg.dv });
    }
    arguments
}

fn main() {
    check_args();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This uses `arg_tbl.iter()`, which will borrow from `arg_tbl`. `String` does not implement the `Copy` trait, so it can't be copied into `arguments`. Because it is borrowed, it can also not be moved. That causes the error message `cannot move out of borrowed content`. Because `String` does implement `Clone`, you can clone it to get a copy. That is why adding a `clone()` on line 13 fixes the problem.

It is also possible to fix this using an iterator which does not borrow; [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). But by-value iterators for arrays are not available at the moment. If you use `arg_tbl.into_iter()`, the array will dereference into a slice, and you will still iterate by reference! But if you change the array into a `Vec`, it will work without having to clone:

```
let arg_tbl = vec![
    ArgsTable {
        dv: "4".to_string(),
    },
    ArgsTable {
        dv: "out.txt".to_string(),
    },
];
let mut arguments: Vec<ArgsTable> = Vec::new();
for arg in arg_tbl.into_iter() {
    arguments.push(ArgsTable { dv: arg.dv });
}
```

You can now also simplify the for loop like this:

```
for arg in arg_tbl {
```

Comment: And you should use `arg_tbl.into_iter().map(|arg| ArgsTable { dv: arg.dv }).collect()` instead of manually `push`ing into the result vector.